# Error when trying to execute ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm just starting with ffmpeg, and i can't get any command to run, they all return

```
"Unable to find a suitable output format for 'i'
i: Invalid argument"
```

The command was just `ffmpeg i StarWars1977.m4v`. Does the input file need too be in somewhere specific, or do I need to copy the file path?

I'm trying to extract frames from a video, but it was giving the same error, so i was trying a simpler test.

Comment: Your question needs a little more information. Do you want to extract certain frames or all of them? BTW, it should always be -i instead of i.

Comment: certain frames, but i wanted to run the command as a test, because it wasn't working.

Comment: Welcome! If you ran the command exactly as you have it in the question, you need a hyphen before the i.  `ffmpeg -i StarWars1977.m4v`

Answer (score 1):

This will get you one frame at the one minute mark.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i "[FilePath]" -frames:v 1 img.png
```